# Facebook: How can I access data contained in response?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Please excuse my beginner status :)  I've been looking at the graph explorer / Getting Started with Facebook Javascript SDK and got the basics up and running.

If I'm correct in my understanding, this code should make a request to the graph... the equivalent of `friends > id` in the graph explorer. Firstly, is this correct?

```
FB.api('/me/friends/id', function(response) {
     // Store response or do something else 
});
```

Secondly, I am not sure how to access this data... I tried looking for documentation on the response object but did not find anything. If my first assumption is correct, the data returned should be along the lines of...

```
{
  "id": "123456", 
  "friends": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "123456"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "123456"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "123456"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "123456"
      }
   ] 
 }
```

So, what I expect to be able to do was access this data through `response.id` etc. - this returned `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Edit.

For Example:

In an example call,

```
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... '); 
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    }
```

This works correctly, and the console logs 'Good to see you ShimmerGeek'.

How can I retrieve friend ids in this same way?

**Edit 2:**

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
                    var friend = new Array(); 
                    for(i = 0; i < response.friends.data.length; i++) {
                        friend[i] = response.friends.data[i].id; 
                        alert(friend[i]); 
                    }
                });
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It should return a regular JSON string... Are you trying to enter `response.id` in the console maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Facebook Developer Graph API tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

The link for `me/friends/id` returns an empty data set. However, the link for `me/friends` returns something more like what you're expecting: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends

Comment: Aha! Cheers. I clicked on the stuff at the side (friends, then id) and it worked fine, but as you say, it doesn't seem to if it's typed in at the console.

Comment: You'll notice that when you click on the side stuff it autofills in the GET submit field. For example, friends -> id gives you `[userid]?fields=friends.fields(id)`

Comment: How can I access the data, then? 

I tried accessing it through `FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
     var friend = new Array(); 
     for(i = 0; i < response.friends.data.length; i++) {
      friend[i] = response.friends.data[i].id; 
      alert(friend[i]); 
     }
                });`

Comment: Try `response.data.length` and `response.data[i]`.